# Hide a certain paragraph for non-logged in users and avoid WP Cache mess

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to hide a certain paragraph from the SINGLE POST in WordPress via PHP content filter.

I developed this filtering script, which works like a sunshine:

```
function hideDaStuff( $content ) {

$paragraphs = explode( '</p>', $content );

foreach ($paragraphs as $index => $paragraph) {
    if(6 == $index){
        $paragraphs[$index] = '<p>Hidden for you ma friend.</p>';
    }else{
        $paragraphs[$index] .= '</p>';
    }

}

return implode( '', $paragraphs );
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'hideDaStuffForDaStranger' );
function hideDaStuffForDaStranger( $content ) {

if ( is_single() && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $content = hideDaStuff( $content );
}

return $content;
}
```

The problem is that WP cache caches the page whatever happens. So if a logged in user visits the page, then the content will show for everybody, and viceversa.

How can I make this specific part cache-independent, while keeping an efficient cache?

Using latest WP version and WP cache.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Actually no need of these filters. Use this format

```
if(is_user_logged_in()){ ?>
    <p>oggedin data</p>
<?php }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put only single condition

```
function hideDaStuffForDaStranger( $content ) {
    if (! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $content = hideDaStuff( $content );
    }

    return $content;
}
```